# Bash script for updating multiple servers not accepting RSA keys

Tags: ssh, bash, rsa

In my environment I manage about 10 Linux servers that require regular package updates. I have a script written to connect to each individually and run the update. Additionally, I have RSA keys installed on each server. Here is my code:

```
hosts=(host1 host2 host3 host4)
read -sp "sudo password (will be used on all servers): " password && echo ""

for host in ${hosts[@]}
do
echo "-------------------------------------------$host----------------"
ssh -t $host "sudo -Sp '' apt-get update <<EOP && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
$password
EOP"
done
```

My goal is to `read` in a password once and have the `apt-get update` run without prompting.

Currently when running the script, I am prompted just after the `echo` statement for a password on each system. When monitoring the /var/log/auth.log file there is no entry generated until after I enter a password. (I would expect a failed login attempt with the RSA key).

When connecting directly to each server, the RSA keys work correctly and can be verified by checking the /var/log/auth.log file.
Using tail -F /var/log/auth.log on the server I can see that the password request is for authentication rather than using the RSA key.

I have checked:

- Permissions on the identity file.
- Using -i to specify an identity file
- using the full path to the identity file.
- adding 'user@' $host to the ssh command to force a specific user.

Comment: `sudo` does take a `NOPASSWD` option. See the `man sudoers`

Comment: sudo isn't the issue. I can comment out the commands within the ssh session and I am still asked for a password.

Comment: Add the `-v` or `-vv` option to your ssh command.  Post errors/logs related to ssh authentication if you can't figure out the problem from there.  PS: Search: Configuration Management tools, puppet, chef, salt, etc.  Management by forloop is so last decade.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I didn't know those tools existed. Salt looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `expect` could be the answer. [Expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net) is a tool for automating interactive applications such as telnet, ftp, passwd, fsck, rlogin, tip, etc. Expect really makes this stuff trivial. Expect is also useful for testing these same applications. And by adding Tk, you can also wrap interactive applications in X11 GUIs.
Also take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780893/use-expect-in-bash-script-to-provide-password-to-ssh-command)